# Disable highlight just for some elements in the listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview that contains diffrent objects . For example { A , B ,B , A , C , etc }
If I click on A it s ok to have highlighted on the item , but if I click on B I don t want to have highlight . I ve put clickable = false in the layout of B component but it does not have effect .

Comment: Use `enabled=false` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disabling ListView items**

You need to override the following methods: in your adapter `isEnabled(int position)` and `areAllItemsEnabled()`. In `isEnabled()` you return true or false depending is list and in `areAllItemsEnabled()` return false.

**Example**

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public CustomAdapter(
            Context context, int textViewResId, CharSequence[] strings) {
        super(context, textViewResId, strings);
    }

...
....    

    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // return false if you want to disable for any element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

extends BaseAdapter and implements isEnabled method

@see: [android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29)